# How to add a keybinding to a QuickPickItem in a VsCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-keybinding

In [VsCode UX guidelines page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/quick-picks) there is an example that shows a keybinding in a QuickPickItem.

[image: VsCode UI with a keybinding in the QuickPickItem]

However, I cannot found any option in [VsCode API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickPickItem) to add it. I am only able to add this type of keybindings in commands in the file package.json

```
"keybindings": [
  {
    "command": "extension-name.option1",
    "key": "ctrl+g", 
    "mac": "cmd+g",   
    "linux": "ctrl+g",
    "win": "ctrl+g"   ,
  }
```

Is it possible to add the keybinding and the icon of the shortcut at the top right of the QuickPickItem like it's shown in the example?

Important, this should not only work, but be visible like in the example.

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/57225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the feeling that screenshot is invalid, and does not represent real APIs.

AFAIK, you can only *declare* keybindings for commands, which must be declared upfront in `package.json`. But elements in items presented in a `QuickPick` are not declared in `package.json`. Instead, you populate them via code. Unless you can  assign a `Command` to some `QuickPickItem` (which I don't remember to be possible), there is no way to acomplish that screenshot.

On the other hand, you may add buttons you your `QuickPickItems` (https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63?ref=refind#_quick-pick-api-improvements). It's not the same thing, but it allows you to give alternative commands to each `QuickPickItem` available to the user.

Comment: Yes, Finally it seems you cannot add keybindings to QuickPickItems. That screenshot is in the VsCode Documentation, but it is wrong, which it's really misleading.
Anyways, thanks for your response. Adding commands could be a workaround but it is not what I was looking.